# Add recieving email adress in contact form

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm working with contact form 
This is part where email is being sending

```
    $emailTo = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Wiadomość ze strony Mud';
    $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
    $body = "Email: $email \n\nKind of frame: $frame \n\nColor suggestion: $color  \n\nInfo about project: $comments";
    $headers = 'From: ' . ' <' . $emailTo . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
    $emailSent = true;
```

Form works good everything is fine, except when I get mail and I want IN MY MAILBOX reply email it shows adress of my webserver
It looks like $headers dont work properly, If I'm right this part of code is responsible for reply adres email "'Reply-To: ' . $email;"

**(IM NOT GOOD IN PHP)**

And my second optional question is how to make stylish email. 
I mean for example in my email when it comes to mailbox it shows

Email: dsadas@dsdas.pl

Kind of frame: dasdsa

Color suggestion: dasdsa

Info about project: dasdsa

**How can I do it bold, color etc ?**

**THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME, CHEERS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go for headers that will allow HTML for email and fix your reply to email:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $emailTo <$emailTo>" . "\r\n";
```

Remember that there is limited support for email when it comes to CSS, you can see things that can't be used here: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: link is great, will be usefull for me of course. But Your code messed up incoming mail, I mean I had to change $headers .= "From: $emailTo <$emailTo>" . "\r\n"; to $headers .= "From: $email <$email>" . "\r\n"; And reply work but body is in same line, what's command for next line ?

Comment: Ok I found solution, only have to switch last $headers to $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email; THANK YOU! And about styling can you maybe send me/ tell me about some tutorial how to do this? now I know whats the limits are, but dont know how to do it.